# react-native-fbsdk 's share plugin error.

Tags: android, ios, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#share-dialogs

I just used this example on official react-native-fbsdk.

But I got this error.

Share fail with error: {
    "framesToPop": 1,
    "code": "EUNSPECIFIED"
}

What am I doing wrong?

I request 'publish_actions' to facebook.
But they said this permission only need for using graph api request.
I am using share dialog plug-in. So I don't need that permission.
Why am I get this error?
I am confusing..

Comment: Having the same issue in my office network. Works fine in my home network. @Dongmin How did u resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your Facebook user is registered as either an admin or a tester in the Facebook Developer portal.

Before even doing that, I tried uninstalling my Facebook app on the phone I was testing on, so it didn't automatically log me in anymore. After I did that, I got a prompt for login/signup.
I was still getting issues after logging in until I updated my user in the Facebook Developer portal.

I hope this helps!